# Migrating groovy syntax to painless syntax - Elastic search 8.9

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

The syntax below mentioned is written in Groovy at the time of 2.3 elastic and now the same syntax has to be migrated to painless 8.9 elastic. Could someone help me with the same in the painless script?

```
ctx._source.bid=bid;
ctx._source.aid=aid;
ctx._source.aname=aname;
```

Comment: Can you provide some more insights as to [the context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/8.9/painless-contexts.html) in which this script needs to be executed?

Comment: for Update by query

Comment: Then the same syntax should work